# ionic cordova plugins undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                    console.log('ionic platform ready')
                    alert('ready')
                        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
                        // for form inputs)
                    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                        alert('keyboard') //why is this not called in android device
                        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                    }
```

why is the alert('keyboard') not called in my android device?
I understand that cordova will not be called browser, but it should be called in real device right?

i tried to

```
alert(JSON.stringify(window.cordova.plugins))
```

but it is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get window.cordova.plugins after I

```
ionic platform rm android
```

and

```
ionic platform add android
```

Comment: this did not solve my problem, still getting the same error.